# Stripe .net "The signature for the webhook is not present in the Stripe-Signature header."

Tags: c#, asp.net, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am using Stripe.net SDK from NuGet. I always get the

> The signature for the webhook is not present in the Stripe-Signature header.

exception from the `StripeEventUtility.ConstructEvent` method.

```
[HttpPost]
public void Test([FromBody] JObject incoming)
{
    var stripeEvent = StripeEventUtility.ConstructEvent(incoming.ToString(), Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"], Constants.STRIPE_LISTENER_KEY);
}
```

The WebHook key is correct, the Request Header contains "Stripe-Signature" keys.

I correctly receive incoming data from the Webhook tester utility (using nGrok with Visual Studio).

the `secureCompare` method seems to be the culprit => [StripeEventUtility.cs](https://github.com/stripe/stripe-dotnet/blob/master/src/Stripe.net/Services/Events/StripeEventUtility.cs)

I tried to manipulate the incoming data from Stripe (Jobject, string, serializing...).  The payload signature may cause some problem.

Has anybody had the same problem?

Comment: Are you using the 'webhook' signing secret or the 'API' signing secret? What fixed it for me was switching from the API secret to the webhook one

Comment: Yes I am using the Webhook secret key contained in Constants.STRIPE_LISTENER_KEY

Comment: Did you ever get a solution to this? I have the same error and I am pretty sure I am using the correct secret

Answer (score 18):

As per @Josh's comment, I received this same error

> The signature for the webhook is not present in the Stripe-Signature header.

This was because I had incorrectly used the API secret (starting with `sk_`) to verify the HMAC on `EventUtility.ConstructEvent`.

Instead, Stripe WebHook payloads are signs with the Web Hook Signing Secret (starting with `whsec_`) as [per the docs](https://stripe.com/docs/webhooks/signatures)

The `Web Hook Signing Secret` can be obtained from the `Developers -> WebHooks` page:

[image: Web Hooks Signing Secret]

Comment: Comment from @Ameya: I received the same error even with valid Signing Key `whsec_xxxxxx`. The issue for me was that with ASP.NET Core 3.xxx versions synchronous operations are not allowed. So we have to construct the Stripe event with the following code.

`using (var sr = new StreamReader(this.HttpContext.Request.Body))
 {
      json = await sr.ReadToEndAsync();
 }
var stripeEvent = Stripe.EventUtility.ConstructEvent(json, Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"], this._stripeSigningSecret, 300, false);`

Answer (score 9):

The error can also occur because you are using the secret from the Stripe dashboard. You need to use the temporary one generated by the stripe cli if you are using the CLI for testing.

To obtain it run this:

```
stripe listen --print-secret
```

Answer (score 2):

I was also receiving the same exception message when I looked at it in the debugger but when I `Console.WriteLine(e.Message);` I received a different exception message.

> Received event with API version 2020-08-27, but Stripe.net 40.5.0 expects API version 2022-08-01. We recommend that you create a WebhookEndpoint with this API version. Otherwise, you can disable this exception by passing `throwOnApiVersionMismatch: false` to `Stripe.EventUtility.ParseEvent` or `Stripe.EventUtility.ConstructEvent`, but be wary that objects may be incorrectly deserialized.

I guess your best bet is to set `throwOnApiVersionMismatch` to `false`;

`EventUtility.ParseEvent(json, header, secret, throwOnApiVersionMismatch: false)`

Answer (score 1):

Im not sure about reason of this, but Json readed from `Request.Body` has a little bit different structure than parsed with `[FromBody]` and Serialized to string.

Also, you need to remove `[FromBody] JObject incoming` because then `Request.Body` will be empty.

The solution you need is:

```
[HttpPost]
public void Test()
{
    string bodyStr = "";
    using (var rd = new System.IO.StreamReader(Request.Body))
      {
          bodyStr = await rd.ReadToEndAsync();
      }
    var stripeEvent = StripeEventUtility.ConstructEvent(bodyStr, Request.Headers["Stripe-Signature"], Constants.STRIPE_LISTENER_KEY);
}
```